# Add Line Break to Title Attribute in Vue JS Template

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to set a `title` attribute on an `<a>` in a Vue JS template that has line breaks in it. I've tried all of the following with no success:

- `\n`
- `&#010;`
- `&#013;`
- An actual line break in the code

How do I make the Vue JS template parser recognize a line break? I'm using Chrome 74 on a Mac.

Comment: You could try: &lt;br&gt; or &#xA;  or &#10;  or &#13;

Comment: a computed title property with `\n` works for me

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a v-bind:title="'Gday\nWorld'">Hello World</a>
```

or if you're ok with a really ugly template:

```
  <a title="Gday
World">Hello World</a>
```

(any indenting will be added to the second line in the tooltip)